# bootstrap 3 ajax loading modals - same content every time

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 3 ajax modals... something such as :

```
<a href="/process/modal.php" data-target="#cmodal" data-toggle="modal">Delete this</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="cmodal" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
    <img src="/assets/img/ajax-modal-loading.gif" alt="" class="loading">
</div>
```

Clicking on the modal multiple times never refreshes the content.  It is always cached.  I searched and read quite a lot here on SO and there were lots of options, but fairly similar.

I decided upon :

```
$("div[id^='cmodal']").on('hidden.bs.modal',
    function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    }
);
```

this should allow me to use modal id's which start with cmodal and anything after it while not 'caching' the content.

It does not work.  Even using a specific id name does not work.  I tried other methods found here on SO for BS3 and those do not work.  What is the deal?  Did they really offer ajax loading of modals which are not 'refreshed' each time?  The entire modal feature with this is useless without being able to change content.

Comment: Nobody?  I see plenty of people having the same problem yet all the 'fixes' I found here on SO are not working.

Comment: The code you are using looks correct. Can you confirm a few things: 1. Does `removeData` get called on the correct element when the modal is hidden? 2. Does the second click of the link send another request? I suspect you are getting a cached response from the server.

Comment: After pulling my hair out trying different methods found here on SO I tried my own method above once more.  What I found is it works perfectly fine in firefox, chrome, opera, and my iphone... it does not work in IE10 or any previous version using f12 dev tools in IE.  What the heck?  Any ideas?

Comment: I take that back... the above only work if I actually make a hardcoded change to the modal page and upload it.  If I insert something like `<?php echo(rand(10,100)); ?>` in the php modal page then it does not update after the first click.

Comment: You might have been on the right track earlier... added ` <FilesMatch "\.(html?|php)$">
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 seconds"
  Header append Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
 </FilesMatch>` into htaccess and it appears to have solved.  Will report back tomorrow with a complete solution after more testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indeed was caching from the server causing the problem.

In htacess I am now using the following which forces no cache on php files.  Combined with the code for the modal this solves the problem and I can now use dynamic content (php) within the modal.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 seconds"
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

I also modified the modal code slightly for more universal application.  There is no reason to worry about ID names in this method and the class is always set for modals in bootstrap 3.

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal',
    function() { 
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    }
);
```